# How to handle classes as datatype in python-dbus

Tags: python, dbus

I'm new to python and dbus, but is there a data binding (= a way to send and receive) python classes via dbus-python?

My class looks like this:

```
class Item:

    def __init__(self, one, two, three, four, five, *more):
        self.one= one
        self.two= two
        self.three= three
        self.four= four
        self.five= five
        self.more= more
```

Where more is a list and one to five are strings. I have a list of these items:

```
list_items = []
list_items.append(Item('Test','Test','Test','Test',more))
```

The dbus part looks like this:

```
@dbus.service.method('com.me.test', in_signature='', out_signature='a(sssssav)')
def get_all_items():
    return list_items
```

Is there an error in my signature or do I have to use a different data structure (tuples?) which can be marshalled?

Comment: You may find [this](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/doc/tutorial.html#data-types) helpful

Comment: @savruk: I read this and because of this link I created that out_signature. But I still get errors. Perhaps I will swap the class with a list.

Comment: In that case I would try this:
1- Change out_signature= "a{sav}"
2- Return Item('Test','Test','Test','Test',more).__dict__ instead of list_items

Answer (score 0):

You could alway use `pickle` or `marshal` and send your data as e.g. a byte-string.
Else you could alternativly create your own DBus-Object by subclassing from `dbus.service.Object`. I would go with the former...

Comment: To pickle the class, send it as a bytestream and unpickle it again seems to be a good solution... I'll look into that!